# Authentication with scoped Application-Default credentials failed GCP

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gmail, credentials

Currently I'm struggling with that kind of issue while obtaining an access token for accessing Gmail user mailboxes. I'm trying to get an access token using [Google Auth Library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest) for Node.js. using that kind of code snippet:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function main() {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 
     'https://mail.google.com/', 
  });
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const token = await auth.getAccessToken();
  console.log(client);
  console.log(token)
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

The thing is that I get the access token with the default list of scopes: `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth'`

When I try to log in with ADC using `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes='https://mail.google.com/'`

I'm being redirected to the google authentication page to choose the account to provide Google Auth Library access to. As soon as I choose the account there appears the screen with that being shown "The application is blocked"

So, guys, is there a way to grant access to Node.js Google Auth Library client library to Gmail mailboxes of the user authenticated by ADC (Application Default Credentials).

I know about impersonation the service account methods and OAuth2.0 authentication, but is it possible to get access token using scoped ADC? And how to make those ADC customly scoped with (https://mail.google.com) access.

Comment: Same here. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for the reply. So what method do you usually use to obtain those access tokens? do you use hashicorp vault to encrypt credentials. Is there a way to generate an access token from Node.js without providing any key.json file?

Comment: When I develop locally, I usually use user credential. But for a few use cases, you must use a service account key file, that is dirty and I'm fighting against that. Currently, I'm contributing to the golang oauth lib to simplify the developer life on their workstation, but in go... I'm bad at Node!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I got you man, really appreciate your replies! Good luck!

Comment: this sounds like an issue in the library. I think that the best option here is to [create an issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187192&template=0) so that the Google team can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into similar issues, and I *think* that what we're both hitting is that we're trying to access *sensitive* or *restricted* api scopes. There's a verification process for those, and so, if you don't strictly need them, it's best to avoid them. I'm guessing your top-level gmail scope is triggering this.

ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/sensitive-scope-verification